# xmlrpc_server has no settings

Tags: 7, services

How do I configure xmlrpc_server?

I am using the Service module, and I need xmlrpc_server. I installed, and enabled it, and it is showing me the following error:

> xmlrpc_server has no settings
>   The server doesn't have any settings that needs to be configured.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

What would you want to configure?

As this message tells you, there is no need to configure anything when using the XMLRPC server. That's all. This isn't an error.